# uibootstrap popver is not opening append dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I am using the pop over for my directive. 
In my directive, I am binding the popover dynamically.

For the first time, if we bind, the popover is working fine. 
If we bind second time with the same settings for the same element, the popover is not triggered.

Here I have stimulated the above usage using the controller. Please refer the following url.

```
To Reproduce the issue

 1. After loading the link, click the append button
 2. Then click on the popover text. The popover will be opened.
 3. Then click on the same append button.
 4. Now click on the popover text, popover won't trigger.

https://plnkr.co/edit/VliC5f7kq93wUDLXT56o?p=preview
```